# Can't remove or hide product images with CSV import

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, import, product-images

I am having an issue where on some of my simple products which are child products of configurable products, their product image (each only has one) does not have the role of "base" so the image will not be displayed on the front end.

I tried fixing this with a product import/update and putting the exsiting image for the product under the "**base_image**" column. This works only now I end up with two images, the old image and the new base image.

I tried to remove the old image by putting only the new image in the "**additional_images**" column but that seemed to be ignored on import and the old image stayed.

I also tried to hide the old image by putting it under the "**hide_from_product_page**" column but that also didn't work.

Anyway I can hide or remove the old/duplicate image with a CSV import?

Screen shot of my test import CSV for one product below:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatly, it is not possible to delete images via csv import. We had the same issue and there is simply no functionality for this. The only solution is to mass delete all images which you can find on stackexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, there is no way to delete pictures with a CSV import. The only way to do this via CSV import is to delete all images and reimport only the ones that you want to remain.